# How do I find which records in a table have no corresponding record in another table

Tags: sql, database, linq

I have two table in my database. One called person and one called team. A person can be on one team.
How do I check to find all the people in person that are not on a team using LINQ or sql??

Comment: only things that showed what was there

Comment: Make a proper question, give example table data, example result.

Comment: you need to be more specific, if we ar enot allowed to use LINQ or SQL what shall we use ?

Comment: @Richard: He seems to be asking for a solution using *either*. I think either one is allowed.

Comment: you are alowed to use linq or SQL... it's just how to find the people who are not on a team

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you represent the linkage of a person to a team.  Do you use a teamID field in person?  If so, what do you do when a person is not on a team?  Keep it null?

```
select * from person where teamID is null
```

Set it to -1?

```
select * from person where teamID == -1
```

Maybe you have a person_team cross table (which would be odd because you said that a person could only be on one team).  If so

```
SELECT * FROM person LEFT OUTER JOIN person_team
 ON (person.id = person_team.personID)
 WHERE person_team.personID IS NULL
```

Or if you have something else -- tell us.

Comment: I would upvote this if it didn't include the "magic number" approach.

Comment: I'm not suggesting it -- but, in case he's using it, that's the way to select.

Answer (score 3):

> A person can be on one team

This makes me guess that you have a TeamID FK field in the person's table that can have null values.

> How do I check to find all the people in person that are not on a team

This will give you all persons not in a team.

```
select *
from person
where TeamID is null
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
 select *
 from person p
 join team t
 on p.TeamId = t.TeamId
 where p.TeamId <> 3
```

or in linq:

```
from p in persons
join t in teams on p.TeamId equals t.TeamId
where t.TeamId != 3
select p
```

both queries will return all persons that are not on the team with ID 3.

Comment: this is a generic solution, but if the community knew your table definitions then we could be more specific.

Comment: He's looking for someone not on a team at all, not people not on a *particular* team, it seems.

Comment: I guess I just miss-read the question then :)

Comment: Evidently not! Looks like you got the checkmark ;)

Comment: If I did get the checkmark it was taken away :(