# Exclude records from results if other records referencing them are linked to a specific value

Tags: mysql, sql

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

There are four tables I have to reference to get the data I am looking for. list, part, listitem, and labelassign.

- The list table has records representing each list
- The listitem table references list.id and represents all of the items on each list
- The part table holds all parts and each part has a unique id
- The labelassign table has friendly labels (like tags) where a partId is referenced in order to label parts.

Visual:

**List**

```
id  name
--  ----
1   part1
2   part2
3   part3
4   part4
```

**Listitem**

```
id  partId  listId
--  ----    ------
1   10      1
2   11      1
3   12      1
4   13      2
5   14      2
```

**Part**

```
id  name
--  ----
1   part1
2   part2
3   part3
4   part4
10  part10
11  part11
12  part12
13  part13
14  part14
```

**Labelassign**

```
id  label          partId
--  -----          ----
1   StandardParts  1
2   StandardParts  2
3   SmallParts     3
4   LargeParts     4
5   HugeParts      5
6   MediumParts    10
7   MediumParts    11
8   MediumParts    12
9   SmallParts     13
10  MediumParts    14
```

To get all lists with a particular label:

```
SELECT list.name
FROM list
INNER JOIN part ON list.name = part.name
INNER JOIN labelassign ON part.id = labelassign.partId AND labelassign.label LIKE '%StandardParts%'
# Using LIKE for '%StandardParts%' because there are variations in the real data but I want them all
```

If the list.name records do not have the **StandardParts** label, they should be excluded from results.

The second part is more tricky and where I have trouble.

Each `list` record has a number of `listitem` records that represent the items on that list. All `list` records which have the **StandardParts** label should have at least one `listitem` record with a **SmallParts** label, but not all do and the ones that don't are what I want to find.

`listitem` records are known as belonging to a particular list by their `listitem.listId` field. So, for each `list` I want to check if any of its `listitem`s have **SmallParts** as a label (by way of checking the matching part, and that part's label as shown above), and if none of those `listitem`s do I want the parent `list` record kept in the result set. Otherwise, the `list.name` should be excluded from the results.

Based on the initial answer from @Eric Brandt, this is what I have so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    l.id,
    l.num
FROM
    list AS l
INNER JOIN
    part AS p1
        ON b.num = p1.num
# Without this up here I didn't get the filtration, lists without the StandardParts label were included in results
INNER JOIN
    labelassign AS la
        ON p1.id = la.partId
        AND la.label LIKE '%StandardParts%'
INNER JOIN
    listitem AS li
        ON l.id = li.listId
INNER JOIN
    part AS p
        ON li.partId = p.id
WHERE
    EXISTS
        (
            SELECT 1
            FROM
                labelassign AS la1
            WHERE
                la1.partId = p.id AND
                la1.label LIKE '%StandardParts%'
        )
    AND NOT EXISTS
        (
            SELECT 1
            FROM
                labelassign AS la2
            WHERE
                la2.partId = p.id AND
                la2.label LIKE '%SmallParts%'
        );
```

The above still returns `list` records which have `listitem` records which have the proper label of **SmallParts**. Again, the goal is to filter those out because I needn't fix those. I'm looking for all `list` records which don't have a `listitem` record with a label of **SmallParts**.

**Expected Results**

```
id  name
--  ----
1   part1
```

Only list.id 1 should be returned because it has a label of StandardParts and none of its listitems have a label of small parts. list.id 2 *does* have a label of StandardParts, but one of its listitems has a label of SmallParts so it should be excluded.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15056431/select-records-which-doesnt-have-specific-records-in-joined-table) touches upon my issue but is mostly Java oriented and the answers do not answer my question.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8212531/how-do-i-find-which-records-in-a-table-have-no-corresponding-record-in-another-t) again brushes by my issue but is really a different problem, that of a non-existent value in another table rather than exclusion based on the presence of a value.

I'm happy to provide more information if I left something out.

Comment: When I first looked at this, I thought that the relationship from `list` to `part` was many-to-may, with `listItem` as a bridge table. Now, though, I see that there are `partId`s in the `list` table, and I don't understand the table relationships at all. I think this really needs identified match and no-match sample data, along with expected results in order to be clear.

Comment: Ok, I've edited the question to hopefully clarify the desired results and what I think should be the way to get it. The tables are much more complex than what I've shown here but I am including the relevant parts and so I removed the list.partId field and reworked my inital query to use list.name instead of list.partId to get the matching part's label. list.name should match part.name which should have a part.id matching labelassign.partId where I get the label for that list from.

Comment: Your sample data seems very irrelevant with only one list with related data in labelassign and you have not included any expected result

Comment: You say that all lists that has the label `StandardParts` should have the label `SmallParts` and all lists without the `SmallParts` should be included but what about lists without both  `StandardParts` and `SmallParts`? Should they also be included?

Comment: I see, I have contradictory sample data. I will edit that.

Comment: @Joakim Danielson Ok, I've corrected the sample data and posted expected results.

Comment: Both list 1 and 2 has label `SmallParts` and none has `StandardParts` so either both or none of them should be included, see my question above. Anyway your expected results doesn't match your sample data.

Comment: list 1 and 2 have a label of `StandardParts`, their list**items** have different labels. list 1's list items all have the label `MediumParts` and one of list 2's list items has a label of `SmallParts`, so list 2 should be excluded while list 1 should be included.

Comment: Yes, I misread somewhat so you are right about SmallParts but neither list 1 or to has a label StandardParts (that label exist for partId 1 and 2 but neither of those are present in listitem)

Comment: And how is labelId relevant here, it's part of your query but it is never explained?

Comment: Both lists and listitems utilize labels for independent reasons, a record does not need to be in listitems to be able to have a label, the table that uses listitems is the part table, and `list` and `listitem` reference the part table, so get labels indirectly. Second, you make a good point about labelId, it is used more widely in my real dataset and I do need to filter on it but here it isn't very relevant. I will remove it.

Comment: The table that uses _labelassign_ is the part table, sorry for the typo in above comment

Comment: “list and listitem reference the part table”, you mean the `list` table reference the `part` table via the `listitem` table because I see no direct link?

Comment: `list.name` matches `part.name`, and `part.id` (for the record with the same `part.name`) matches `labelassign.partId` which is how a list record is associated with a label. A `list` record can be associated with a `part` record, and a `listitem` record can also be associated with a `part` record. The `part` records are what get labels assigned in the `labelassign` table.

Answer (score 0):

You want a « LEFT JOIN » on items having « SmallParts », with a WHERE clause that filters out matching rows. You can use « SELECT DISTINCT » to avoid duplicates. Finally, I suspect that you do not need to JOIN on table « part », I removed it.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    list.id, 
    list.name
FROM 
    list
    INNER JOIN listitem ON list.id = listitem.listId
    INNER JOIN labelassign l1 ON listitem.partId = l1.partId AND l1.labelId =  AND l1.label LIKE '%StandardParts%'
    LEFT JOIN labelassign l2 ON l2.partId = listitem.partId AND l2.label LIKE '%SmallParts%';
WHERE l2.partId IS NULL
```

Comment: This isn't filtering out list records without a part label like '%StandardParts%' and also is returning list records that have a listitem record tied to a part with a 'SmallParts' label. I don't think my inner join usage is filtering correctly.

Comment: @DustyVargas this should work already... I simplified the query (unnecessary JOIN on « part »). However I see a glitch in your test data, where most « partId »s from table listitem do not exist in tables « part » and « labelassign »

Comment: That's correct, I am not posting complete data (in the sense that I won't include the entire table, it's very large) but I've added the referenced parts for clarity'. I am still getting extra records though. I feel like the second INNER JOIN should keep me from getting list records where the label isn't like '%StandardParts%' but that isn't the case. I have a ton more.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding the reason for the last statement but labelassign.partId is never null

Answer (score 0):

I would try an `EXISTS` clause to find `list.id`s that have a `StandardParts` label, and then a `NOT EXISTS` clause to limit those results to the lists where no parts have the `SmallParts` label.

```
SELECT 
  l.id, 
  l.name
FROM 
  list AS l
INNER JOIN 
  listitem AS li
    ON l.id = li.listId
INNER JOIN 
  part AS p
    ON li.partId = p.id
WHERE 
  EXISTS
    (
      SELECT 1
      FROM 
        labelAssign AS la1 
      WHERE 
        la1.partId = p.id AND
        la1.label LIKE '%StandardParts%'
    )
  AND NOT EXISTS
    (
      SELECT 1
      FROM 
        labelAssign AS la1 
      WHERE 
        la1.partId = p.id AND 
        la1.label LIKE '%SmallParts%'
    );
```

Comment: I believe you're missing an AND after la1.labelId = 20 (I won't edit because I'm new to mysql and unsure if I'm correct). Same as the other answer though, I get results for lists who's label is not 'StandardParts' and lists which have listitems whose label is 'Small Parts'.

Comment: Also, can you explain what SELECT 1 is doing in this case?

Comment: In a correlated sub-query (which is what you call the things in the `[NOT] EXISTS` clauses, you're only checking to see if any record meets the criteria. Since you're not returning any results, you just need to `SELECT` _something_ and `1` is lightweight. As to not getting the expected results, if time allows, I'll take another pass with the updated sample data you've posted.